# How to limit the length of a border in css?

Tags: html, css, border

I have a screenshot as shown below which I have to replicate in html/css.

[image]

Attached is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3oy1fjqL/1/embedded/result) for the above screenshot which I am able replicate at this moment.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes **I need to make in the inline styles** in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3oy1fjqL/1/embedded/result)   so that I am able to limit the length of a border.  At this moment, it is covering the full screen.

The snippets of code which I have used in order to achieve the above screenshot are:

```
<tr>
   <td style="text-align:left;padding-left:10%;padding-bottom:1%;">poster: donald duck</td>
   <td style="text-align:center;;padding-left:10%;padding-bottom:1%;">customer: donald duck</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code you gave in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3oy1fjqL/1/embedded/result),you set the width attribute in the table tag width="100%", try set it to whatever value you want.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="font-size: 
20px;
...
">
```

to

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600" style="font-size: 
20px;
...
">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing this.

You need to add `margin: 0 auto;` to align it to center

Set the `width` of the `table` so it will have a limit and will not occupy the whole screen.

Please see the code below.

```html
 <tr>
      <td>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="50%" style="
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #484848;
    border-top: 2px solid #484848;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
">
          <tr>
            <td style="text-align:left;padding-bottom:1%;">poster: donald duck</td>
            <td style="text-align:left;padding-bottom:1%;padding-left: 10%;">customer: donald duck</td>
          </tr> 
          <tr>
            <td style="text-align:left;padding-bottom:1%;">phone: 613-613-6134</td>
            <td style="text-align:left;padding-bottom:1%;padding-left: 10%;">phone: 613-613-6134</td>
          </tr> 
          <tr>
            <td style="text-align:left;padding-bottom:1%;">email: dduck@gmail.com</td>
            <td style="text-align:left;padding-bottom:1%;padding-left: 10%;">email: dduck@gmail.com</td>
          </tr>       
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
```